How is time complexity calculated for inner loops?
I have this code to analyse:
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}

What is the time complexity of this code?
Assuming n=10:
For every iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop runs n times, i.e. 10*10 = 100 times. Whereas the outer loop runs n times, i.e. 10 times. So isn't the time complexity O(n)*O(n²)=O(n³)? I see it as O(n²).

I have no idea where you got n^3. The inner loop takes n steps for every iteration of the outer loop. The outer loop takes n steps, therefore the inner loop runs a total of n*n steps, or O(n^2).

If you consider every loop by itself, you get a O(n) for both loops. Because the 2nd loop is inside the outer loop, you have to multiply it so you get: O(n) * O(n) = O(n²).

if you also had some function in the outer loop, it would be like O(n + n*n)  - not O(n * n*n) - and O(n + n*n) = O(n * (n+1)) is considered O(n*n) since constants are ignored (constants are very small compared to large numbers [infinite]) -- otherwise, you do not need to add O(n) since the outer loop is already being included in O(n*n) (one of the n)


I see it as O(n²).

O(²) would be correct (but see below for a nuance).
It is true that the outer loop has  iterations, but if you already count ² for the total of inner loop iterations, then it is an addition, not a multiplication. So with this approach you could say it is O( + ²), which is O(²).
But the situation is complicated by the printing of the number. If we just gloss over that, and consider that printing a number has O(1) time complexity, then we are done. But fact is that the printing effort is determined by the number of characters to print. To print a number with five digits takes longer than printing a number with just one.
The number of digits in a number  is O(log), and thus the time complexity of the print call is O(log). In total we thus have O((log1 + log2 + ... + log)) which is O((log)), which is O(²log).

So what is the correct way to calculate? Should that be based on the outer loop or based on the inner loop?

@Varun it should be based on the whole.

Always be careful with code analysis: check the number of iterations each loop makes, which sometimes is also dynamic. Often it is good to find which is the atomic statement/expression that gets executed the most times, which is likely located in the inner loop. In this case it could be the print call (although the loop condition is evaluated one time more than a loop iterates). The print call is executed ² times, so that is a good start. Multiply that with the time complexity of printing, and you're done.

Whether you follow a reasoning that leads you to O( + ²) or with another reasoning that gives you O(²), it doesn't matter, as both are equivalent.

Here is the analysis :
The time complexity of this algorithms is :

O(n²)

Time complexity for a for loop always depends on the number of times that loop is executed rather been specific the code in the loops is executed.
In the case of for loop also the time complexity depends on the number of time the code in it is executed.which is decided by the beginning and ending condition and the incrementation of the iterative variable.
In Your Algorithms :
Your have used nested for loop.In nested for their 2 loop
inner loop and outer loop, particularly the inner for is executed till the iterative variable of outer loop is reached(or the ending condition satisfies) which is : i<=n
in your case. So the outer for loop will execute the inner for loop n time.
Similarly the inner loop will be executed n times because of it ending condition : j<=n
Conclusion :
Inner for loop executes n times and outer loop executes inner for loop n times
So we can conclude that nested for is executed n*n=n² time (In worst case scenarios) 
We know output statement take 1 unit time so the in for loop it is executed n times
Since,for larger values of n n²>>>n
Thus we can say the worst case time complexity of your algorithm is O(n²)
